# Chrome Extension: Close opened tab, regardless of if its the current one

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is the background.js of my chrome extension. I am a newbie on programming chrome extensions.
How can I close the tab that is opened in this example regardless of if the tab is the current one or not?

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, 
        function (tabs) {
            url = tabs[0].url;
            if (url=="http://www.example.com"){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //would be nice to have this executed after EVERYTHING on the page is loaded
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"jquery-1.11.1.min.js"});
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"contentscript.js"});
                },17000);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    tabs[0].remove();
                    alert('tab removed');
                },25000);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: You should use `chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);` to close the tab. See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove

Answer (score 0):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948929/chrome-extension-close-opened-tab-regardless-of-if-its-the-current-one#comment46156791_28948929) from [gui47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4204304/gui47) is correct - just use chrome.tabs.remove(... the tab id you want to remove ...)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this code could use improvement, *assuming I understood your intent*.

Imagine that you middle-click a link in a tab. It creates a tab in the background, and calls `onCreated` listener for it.

Yet you query for the active tab, and get the initial tab, not the new one.

1. You should use the fact that the tab information [is passed into `onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated).

   ```
   chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) { // Can have a parameter!
     /* use tab.url and tab.id */
   });
   ```
2. When you call `executeScript`, it still obeys [the `run_at` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), which is by default at `document_idle`. That means it will not execute until the static DOM is ready at least.

   So no need for the timeout. To be extra safe, you can wrap your content script code in `$(document).ready()`

   If you want to wait until the resources like images are loaded, you can use `load` event of the body.

   If you need to wait until a specific event happens / some scripts execute in the page, you can use timeout and/or something like [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). However, it would make more sense then to add this waiting to `contentscript.js` and not the injecting code.

   ```
   chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) { // Can have a parameter!
     // Assuming you want to check the address contains that and not exactly it
     if(~tab.url.indexOf("http://www.example.com")) {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"jquery-1.11.1.min.js"});
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"contentscript.js"});
     }
   });
   ```
3. Finally, if you want to close the page, you could call `chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id)`.

   But it might be better to simply close it from the content script - it might know better when to do it.

   From the content script, you can simply use `window.close()` if your extension opened the tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);` to close the tab. 
See [chrome.tabs.remove( )](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove).

Answer (score 0):

Use `chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);`

Whereas tabId is the id of your tab. If you don't know where to get the tabId you can use the below code in your background.js.

```
chrome.tabs.query(
    {
        active:true,
        windowType:"normal",
         currentWindow: true
    },
    function(d)
    {
        tabId = d[0].id;
    });
```